# Moq - how can I mock a non-virtual member like HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd, moq

I can't seem to use *Moq* to mock `HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority` because it is a non-virtual method. I get the following exception:

```
{"Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: p => p.HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority"}
```

How can I overcome this? Below are my Test methods:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ForgottenPasswordPost_Requested_CaptchaCorrectEmailExists()
{
    _testModel.ControllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Session["Captcha"]).Returns("HelloWorld");
    _testModel.ControllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority).Returns("www.localhost.com");
    _testModel.QMember.Setup(m => m.MemberExistsWithEmail(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);


    var controllerUnderTest = _testModel.ReturnController();
    ForgottenPasswordModel model = new ForgottenPasswordModel() { Captcha = "HelloWorld" };

    //Act
    var actionResult = (RedirectToRouteResult)controllerUnderTest.ForgottenPassword(model);

    Assert.AreEqual("ForgottenPasswordConfirm", actionResult.RouteValues["action"]);
    Assert.AreEqual("a", actionResult.RouteValues["controller"]);
}

public class TestModel
{
    public UnregisteredController Controller { get; set; }
    public Mock<ControllerContext> ControllerContext { get; set; }
    public Mock<IQ_Member> QMember { get; set; }

    public TestModel()
    {
        ControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        QMember = new Mock<IQ_Member>();
    }

    public UnregisteredController ReturnController()
    {
        Controller = new UnregisteredController(QMember.Object);
        Controller.ControllerContext = ControllerContext.Object;
        return Controller;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962010/moq-invalid-setup-on-a-non-overridable-member-x-x-getbytitleasdf), you can only implement virtual/abstract members using Moq.

In general non-ASP.NET MVC cases, you can either

1. use a mocking tool which would allow for the overriding of non-virtual, concrete class members or
2. Write your own wrapper classes with pass-through methods to the static/non-virtual members, extract interfaces from these wrapper classes, and then design the rest of your code to depend on these interfaces, which can then easily be mocked and dependency injected.

I would recommend #2 over #1 above even though it results in a fair amount of work, because #2 will almost certainly result in code which better adheres to the [Dependency Inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

However in your case I think there is a fairly simple solution.

In the line of code

```
_testModel.ControllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority).Returns("www.localhost.com");
```

- `.HttpContext` is abstract so it can be mocked
- `.Request` is abstract so it can be mocked
- `.Url` is virtual so it can be mocked
- `.Authority` is a non-virtual string property and this is what is giving you problems

Try this instead, since `.Url` is the deepest part that you can mock:

```
_testModel.ControllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://www.localhost.com"));
```