# System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am getting a NotSupportedException error message on my Unit Test using Moq

> System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member

Unit Test Code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestEmailNotSentOut()
{
  // ...

  var dataAccess = new Mock<TjiContext>();       
  var mockSetStock = new Mock<DbSet<Stock>>();
  mockSetStock.As<IQueryable<Stock>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(stockList.Provider);
  mockSetStock.As<IQueryable<Stock>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(stockList.Expression);
  mockSetStock.As<IQueryable<Stock>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(stockList.ElementType);
  mockSetStock.As<IQueryable<Stock>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(stockList.GetEnumerator());
  dataAccess.Setup(m => m.Stocks).Returns(mockSetStock.Object);
```

A suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768767/invalid-setup-on-a-non-virtual-overridable-in-vb-member) says to mark it as `virtual`, but I'm not sure what needs to be marked as virtual?

The error is occurring at this line:

```
  dataAccess.Setup(m => m.Stocks).Returns(mockSetStock.Object);
```

Comment: At what line you are getting this error?

Comment: base on your code seems that you are using Entity framework. if so, the problematic line is ׳dataAccess.Setup(m => m.Stocks).Returns(mockSetStock.Object);׳. you can't fake this line using ׳Moq׳. (i believe dataAccess is StocksModelContext : DbContext{
  public DbSet<Stock> Stocks{ get; set; }
})

Comment: The error is occurring on line    dataAccess.Setup(m => m.Stocks).Returns(mockSetStock.Object);  I am using EntityFramework   var dataAccess = new Mock<TjiContext>(); public DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }  So can that line be changed or do i need to find another way to test without using Moq?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using EF of at least V6 and based on this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn314429.aspx) (look at the Blogs element) which is doing a very similar thing to you. I'd guess that your problem is that your `dataAccess`, whatever it is doesn't declare `Stocks` as virtual.

So it should look something like this:

```
public virtual DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -3):

The property or function you're trying to setup needs to be declared as

```
public virtual
```

otherwise Moq can't create an inherited class, which overrides this function or propterty, which is nessecary, when you want to setup it.

Comment: OP is aware of marking virtual. He is not aware of what thing to make virtual.

Comment: One of the properties he wants to setup, so either Provider, Expression, ElementType, or GetEnumerator(). And I think my explanation of what happens when mocking, helps him to determine which of these.