# MoQ : Property is correctly set as virtual but still have invalid setup on a non-virtual member

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, moq, mstest

I'd like to unit test a DbContext which inherits from **IdentityDbContext**

I am getting a `NotSupportedException` error message with the very common message :

> System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member

To find some clues I already read a bunch of posts. Here are some samples:

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936349/system-notsupportedexception-invalid-setup-on-a-non-virtual-overridable-in-vb)
- [This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670902/why-does-the-property-i-want-to-mock-need-to-be-virtual)
- [This Last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768767/invalid-setup-on-a-non-virtual-overridable-in-vb-member)

Obviously, the solution appears to *set the dbSet as virtual*. What I've done.

Bad luck, the error remains.

Here is my **IdentityDataContext** :

```
public class IdentityDataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{      
    public virtual DbSet<Search> Searches { get; set; }

    public IdentityDataContext()
        : base("LocalDb",
              throwIfV1Schema: true)
    {            
    }

    public static IdentityDataContext Create()
    {
        return new IdentityDataContext();
    }
}
```

Here is my **Search** POCO :

```
public class Search : BaseEntity
{
    //BaseEntity is just an abstract class with createdAt,Id,updatedAt property
    public string ConsumerIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }         
}
```

Finally here is my **Set Up Method** :

```
[TestInitialize]
public void SetupTest()
{
    //DataInitializer.GetAllSearches() returns a List of "Search"

    _searches = DataInitializer.GetAllSearches();

    var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Search>>();
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<Search>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(_searches.AsQueryable().Provider);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<Search>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(_searches.AsQueryable().Expression);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<Search>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(_searches.AsQueryable().ElementType);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<Search>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(_searches.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());
    dbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<Search>())).Callback<Search>(_searches.Add);

    _dataContextMock = new Mock<IdentityDataContext>()
    {
        CallBase = true
    };

    // The error appears here ---------------- _
    dataContextMock.Setup(x   => x.Searches).Returns(dbSet.Object);
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    _dataContextMock.Setup(x => x.Set<Search>()).Returns(dbSet.Object);

    _searchRepository = new SearchRepository(_dataContextMock.Object);
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) no need to unit test DbContext. Microsoft would have done extensive testing on it already.

2) if the DbContext is to be used as a dependency for another class then abstract the dbcontext

```
public interface IDataContext {
    DbSet<Search> Searches { get; set; }
}

public class IdentityDataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDataContext { ... }

public class SearchRepository {
    public SearchRepository(IDataContext context) { ... }
}
```

Don't have you classes depending on concretions but rather on abstractions. `IdentityDataContext` is an implementation detail that dependent classes need not know about.

This would then allow more flexibility for testing

```
Mock<IDataContext> _dataContextMock;

[TestInitialize]
public void SetupTest() {

    //DataInitializer.GetAllSearches() returns a List of "Search"
    _searches = DataInitializer.GetAllSearches();
    var queryable = _searches.AsQueryable();

    var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Search>>();
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<Search>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<Search>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<Search>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<Search>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());
    dbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<Search>())).Callback<Search>(_searches.Add);


    _dataContextMock = new Mock<IDataContext>();

    _dataContextMock.Setup(x => x.Searches).Returns(dbSet.Object);

    _dataContextMock.Setup(x => x.Set<Search>()).Returns(dbSet.Object);

    _searchRepository = new SearchRepository(_dataContextMock.Object);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. That's an approach  I hadn't thought about. 

I read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_7) on MSDN. I'm wondering why this other approach could not work in my case ?

Basically, they use a Service while I implement repository and unit of work design patterns . But those have the same purpose : managing models. Am I wrong ?