# How to setup a non-virtual members uning nunit moq technique?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have a code as:

```
public bool MethodName(int parameter)
{
   using(var service = new XYZServiceClient())
   {
      return service.AnyMethod();
   }
}
```

When I tried to setup the MOQ, I got following error in the setup:

> System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a non-virtual
>   (overridable in VB) member: x => x.AnyMethod()

Comment: I think this is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768767/invalid-setup-on-a-non-virtual-overridable-in-vb-member

Comment: Moq does not support non virtual members.