# How do I mock base class function calls using MOQ?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

In the below given scenario, I have added reference to someExternal.Library.dll  and derived a class named `MyClass` from `BaseClass`. `MyClass` invokes `MakeCall()` method of `BaseClass` internally in its methods. Here, the `BaseClass` is a concrete class which does not implement any Interface and also the `MakeCall()` method is a non-virtual method.

in such a scenario, how do I mock only the `MakeCall()` method of base class?
I want to write unit tests for `MyClass`

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass
{

public void DoSomething()
{
    //someExternal.Library.dll is referenced to the project
    // Makecall() is available to this class through inheritance 

    MakeCall();
    ...

}

    public bool DoSomethingElse()
{
        ...
    }
}
```

in the above snippet I want to write unit Test for `MyClass` and I should be able to Mock `obj.MakeCall();` method call using MoQ.

NOTE: MOQ is the only mocking framework I am allowed to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your base method neither implements any interface nor marked as virtual, Moq can't help you at that specific scenario, since it generates a proxy that will implement the interface or create a derived class that overrides a method in order to intercept calls.

If your base class is not a legacy code you can't touch by any means, I would recommend to add an interface and mock it directly.

Otherwise, see the following answer for Moq alternatives that work directly with the IL and can mock sealed classes:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21793891/3400897