# Moq - Setup of Async Method. Error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm trying to setup a method on a Mocked object that is async.

As the object is not crucial to my actual test, i just want the method to return an integer, which is its return type.

My code is below :-

```
_legacyUnitOfWorkMock.Setup(x => x.CommitAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult<int>(1));
```

However, I get the following error message :-

> System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a non-virtual
>   (overridable in VB) member: x => x.CommitAsync()

Can anyone point out why this code would fail?

Comment: Can you post more about what _legacyUnitOfWorkMock is, In particular the CommitAsync signature?

Comment: When the method is not [virtual](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962010/moq-invalid-setup-on-a-non-overridable-member-x-x-getbytitleasdf), then it can't be mocked with Moq.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
_legacyUnitOfWorkMock.Setup(x => x.CommitAsync()).ReturnsAsync(1);
```

Or

```
_legacyUnitOfWorkMock.Setup(x => x.CommitAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(1));
```